# Dealing with org-macros: Undefined org macro; aborting

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Do I have to activate something to allow Org-mode 9 to process macros?
An org-file with the following content gives me an error on export:

```
#+MACRO CANVAS @@html:<div align=center><canvas id="$1"></canvas></div>@@
{{{CANVAS(thename)}}}
```

Would somebody be able to point me in the right direction?!

Error message:

> cond: Undefined Org macro: canvas; aborting

Comment: Missing colon in `#+MACRO:` ?

Comment: I feel like I should delete the question now.... =/ Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Comment: Nah - leavie it. It's a useful reminder :-)

Comment: But you or mutbuerger should add the solution to the question and you should accept it. It's more visible that way instead of the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In-buffer settings start with ‘#+’, followed by a keyword, a colon, and then a word for each setting.
>
> (info "(org) In-buffer settings")

Your macro definition lacks the colon: `#+MACRO:`.